# Making two arrays occupy same memory region in C language

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, memory-management

<s>Arrays in C are actually constant pointers.</s> *The pointer to the first element of an array is a constant.* Therefore it seems impossible to assign an address value to the <s>array pointer</s> *pointer pointing the firs element of the array*.

But in some situations it might be useful to have two arrays point to the same location in memory.

So how can I make two arrays point to the same location in such fashion :

```
int a[10];
int b[10];

a = b; // Not possible
```

---

What is below seems to be a valid solution. But, are there alternatives?

```
int *a;
int *b;
int c[10];

a = c;  // If you change the value "a" points to
b = c;  // it will be observed on "b"

a[2] = 5;
printf("Output is %d", b[2]);

>> Output is 5
```

Comment: "Arrays in C are actually constant pointers" is *wrong*. Arrays can *decay* to pointers (to their first elements) but aren't pointers in and of themselves. This is what happens in the second example with e.g. `a = c` which is equivalent to `a = &c[0]`. I think this misunderstanding is what leads you to believe you can make overlapping arrays like in the first example. The solution, which is shown in the second example using actual pointers, is the correct way.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. When you implicitly convert one to a pointer, the pointer is generated on the fly.

Comment: Arrays are constant pointer to their first element, so you can't reassign them: their address is set at compilation time and is stored in a read-only segment of the program, if you want to be able to reassign them you need pointers assigned at runtime: malloc'ed ones. ```int  * a = malloc(sizeof(int) * numbers_count);```, ```int * b = a;``` And if you want only a part of both arrays to be shared: ```int * a = malloc(sizeof(int) * (count_in_a + count_in_b - intersection_size));```

Comment: You can use pointers as arrays, in this case, since ```a``` is a memory block containing X integers, ```a[2]``` is equivalent to ```*(a + 2)```, the third element (first one being ```a[0]``` <-> ```*(a + 0)```

Comment: @AR7CORE "Arrays are constant pointer to their first element" is wrong. See comments above.

Comment: @AR7CORE Could you provide your comments as a full answer ? malloc() approach is nice.

Comment: @Xfce4: Would you mind sharing with us, what the deeper reason for this question is. I sense a XY problem in the making, and maybe there's a more straightforward approach to whatever you try to accomplish, other than what lies down the path you've chosen.

Comment: There are tricks one could play with the linker to make two different declared arrays reference the same memory.  But it's not a good idea, since the compiler is allowed to assume that arrays with different names are different objects, and so for instance it might reorder accesses to them.  You'd have to make everything `volatile` to have a chance of this being safe, and this would basically block all optimizations.  (Note that this does not apply to **pointers**.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays behave like pointers to their first element, but you can't reassign them:

```c
int a[] = { 1, 2 };
int b[] = { 3, 4 };
b = a; // compilation error: b is constant
```

The reason is their address, being known at compile time, is stored in a read-only segment of the program, and writing in a read-only segment would be a segmentation fault.

A pointer is a type which contains an address, it can be assigned at runtime.
If you don't know at compile-time how much memory you need, you can ask some to your system with dynamic allocation:

```c
int * integers = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3); // dynamic array of size 3
// or 
int * integers = malloc(sizeof(* integers) * 3);
```

If you want 2 arrays to point to the same memory:

```c
char * interval1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2); // sizeof() useless here, char is defined as 1 byte 
interval1[0] = 'A'; // equivalent to *(p + 0) = 'A'
interval1[1] = 'Z';  // equivalent to *(p + 1) = 'Z'

char * interval2 = interval1;
```

But the interest is rather limited if both variables are in the same function.

I didn't add checks, but you should always check for NULL after allocation, and free() when you don't need the memory anymore.

TDLR: if you need to reassign an address, don't use array-type, but pointer-type, it's made to be dynamic.

Comment: Re “The reason is their address, being known at compile time, is stored in a read-only segment of the program”: Addresses of static and automatic arrays are largely combinations of immediate operands of instructions and base addresses held in registers that are set up by the program loader. In modern general-purpose operating systems, they are not usually stored in read-only segments. And the reason we cannot modify the address of an array (or any object) is because of language semantics, not where they are stored. If the semantics were different, we would change where addresses were stored.